# Error on getting Image on Ajax Response

Tags: php, ajax, fabricjs

I made an application on php and Fabric.js. Based on the parameters the image is changed on canvas.
[image: This is the screenshot of the appliation]

I want to fetch this image from a different page via ajax call based on the parameters.

But now when i am sending the GET request, It sending the whole HTML page.

Please help me.

Comment: show the code .

Comment: which code? The fabric js code or the ajax code?

Comment: Which ever relevant to the question.

Comment: this is the js code .https://jsfiddle.net/xfq3o727/

Comment: Where is your `ajax` code?

Comment: it is just a normal ajax call.

Comment: show the `php` code where you getting image.

Comment: var url = '<?php echo  Mage::getUrl('liveeditor/index/createimage')?>';

    var default_sku = jQuery(this).find('img').attr('data-default-sku');

    jQuery.ajax({
                url: url,
               data: {metal:1,style:1,stone:1,color:color},
                type: "POST",
                success: function(response)
                {
                      
                  
                 }
              });

Comment: this is the ajax call

Comment: place `exit()` or `die()` in your php code just after the return or echo of image.

Comment: but its returning the whole html not image

Comment: show you php code.

Comment: http://onlinedevserver.biz/html/ranit/jwl-build/index.php?metal=2&view=1&style=2&stone=1&color=1.6,1.1,.4

Comment: pls check this link , this is the live verstion. try to change the parameter. you will get another image

Comment: edit the question and paste your php code.

Comment: what i want, get this image to anothr page via ajax call based on the parameters, you got me sir?

Comment: Yep,  Can you paste your php code